# If $|B\times A| = 15$ ,evaluate: $|A\cap B|$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, relations

If $|B\times A| = 15$ and $|A\times B \backslash B \times B| = 12$.

Evaluate: $|A\cap B|$

I tried for myself and got to the conclusion that $|A\times B \cap B \times B| = 3  $

I couldn't get by myself to the point where I know how to evaluate  $|A\cap B|$

Some help?:)
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $(A\times B)\cap (B\times B)=(A\cap B)\times B$

Comment: Can you show me how you realized that?

Comment: It looked like something that might be true (some sort of distributive property), and it did in fact work out to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

$|B \times A| = nm = 15$
$|(A \times B) \setminus (B \times B)| = | (A \setminus B) \times B| = (|A| - |A \cap B|)  \times |B| = (m-x)n = 12$
$mn-(m-x)n=3, nx=3$
$(m-x)3/x=12$
$m/x=5$
easy to guess that $m=5, n=3, x=1$
$|A \cap B| = 1$